# I am trying to pass may multiple data on screen to another screen in flutter but it shows the Invalid argument error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Hello I am trying to pass may multiple data on one screen to another screen in flutter but it shows the Invalid argument error. I couldn't recognize where hav the error.I provide my navigation part code and antoher activity part code.

=>Home Activity navigation part method.

-this is the navigate method.

```
getItemAndNavigation(BuildContext context){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>resultScanner(
      scanResult: scannedResult,
      resultType: resultType,
    )));
  }
```

=> this is my second activity code.

```
class resultScanner extends StatelessWidget {
  final scanResult;
  final resultType;

  resultScanner({Key key, @required this.scanResult, this.resultType})
      : super(key: key);

  String currentTime = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        title: Text(
          "Result",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Result type = ' + resultType,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
          ),
          Text(
            'Description = ' + scanResult,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

=>This is the erros showing.

```
> The following ArgumentError was thrown building resultScanner(dirty,
> state: _resultScannerState#7c9c8): Invalid argument(s)
> 
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    resultScanner
> file:///F:/Work/QReader/qreader/qreader/lib/screens/homeui.dart:458:34
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
> #0      _StringBase.+ (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:267:57)
> #1      _resultScannerState.build (file:///F:/Work/QReader/qreader/qreader/lib/screens/result_scan.dart:46:30)
> #2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4663:28)
> #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4546:15)
> #4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not defined the type, on the second screen.

```
class resultScanner extends StatelessWidget {
  final scanResult;
  final resultType;
```

}

Change it to `final String scanResult`  and `final String resultType`
Or Maybe whatever you want them to be.

There is another problem with this code in the print Statement:

```
Text(
       'Result type = ' + resulType,
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
        ),
```

It should be:

```
Text(
      'Result type = $resultType'
       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
    ),
```

Same goes for scanResult.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little surprised it compiles at all, but you did not give your variables any type.

So this line is basically having some religious faith in the fact that the variables passed are something that can be concatenated with a plus symbol:

```
'Result type = ' + resultType,
```

Give your two variables `scanResult` and `resultType` a type (maybe they are strings?) and then figure out whether a simple plus is the right way to concatenate them with another string.

Comment: Fun fact though, you don't need types in dart, it just reverts to being a dynamic type. So the code is trying to perform string + dynamic and failing.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "faith": hoping that at runtime, the dynamic will hold an object that can do that :)